# Very fast memory write (Windows)

Tags: memory, process

I am using in C++:

```
While(1){
WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)value, &newValue, (DWORD)sizeof(newValue), NULL);
}
```

Is there faster way to write to memory (in Windows)?

Comment: What's the point of writing the same data to memory in a loop? What do you want to achieve? How many bytes are you writing? If it's only 4 bytes, a variable assignment may be faster.

Comment: I will use sizeof(byte), thanks Thomas. I have another program which is very quickly writing another variable to that address, and I want to "freeze" it to earlier state.

Comment: Ok, then `hProc` refers to a different process and a simple variable assignment is not possible. Looks fine to me, don't have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this faster is to make a DLL which modifies that memory address and inject it into the target process.  WriteProcessMemory() requires the overhead of calling into the kernel while de-referencing the memory locally is done with just a couple assembly instructions.